# Getting System error when trying to access notification tab

Tags: server, landscape

I am trying to explore landscape server in my lab environment everything is working as expected. I am using self signed certificate in lab environment.

In my staging environment i am using letsencrypt certificate for HTTPS.

I have added 2 host in landscape and both are showing on dashboard and all tab are working as expected except notification tab which show any system is asking for reboot or package upgrading etc.

I am getting below error in `appserver.log`

```
Aug 19 12:46:15 appserver-1 ERR  https://abc.xyz.com/account/standalone/alert/13/resolve#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 129, in publish#012    obj = request.traverse(obj)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/browser.py", line 540, in traverse#012    ob = super(BrowserRequest, self).traverse(obj)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/http.py", line 457, in traverse#012    ob = super(HTTPRequest, self).traverse(obj)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/base.py", line 260, in traverse#012    obj = publication.traverseName(self, obj, entry_name)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/app/publication/zopepublication.py", line 198, in traverseName#012    ob2 = adapter.publishTraverse(request, nm)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/routes/publisher.py", line 158, in publishTraverse#012    request.response.redirect(location, trusted=trusted)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/browser.py", line 759, in redirect#012    return super(BrowserResponse, self).redirect(location, status, trusted)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/http.py", line 886, in redirect#012    % target_host)#012ValueError: Untrusted redirect to host '1.2.3.4:443' not allowed.
```

If i access the landscape dashboard using `IP` instead of `domain name i.e abc.xyx.com` then its working fine.

So its issue with redirection but ubable to fix it.
I have change the domain name and IP for security purpose.

Please help me.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on above issue?

Comment: Any help on above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed. By following the below steps:

```
1. Go to Organisatios->Settings
2. In Root URL provide your domain name. Earlier i have my IP now its replaced with domain name and everything is working fine
```

Thanks.